# ASP.NET Core Razor page post action throws HTTP 405 error

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an extremely simple Razor test page, but the post action throws an HTTP 405 error, and the code in the `OnPostAsync` method never executes, which is required for further processing.

```
@page
@model SubmitTestModel

<div>
    <h2>
        Submit test
    </h2>
</div>

<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The Page model consists of nothing more than

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test.Pages
{
    public class SubmitTestModel : PageModel
    {
        public SubmitTestModel()
        { }

        [BindProperty]
        public IFormFile UploadFile { get; set; }

        public IActionResult OnGetAsync()
        {
            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "405 Method Not Allowed
The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested resource." Your server does not allow 'post'.

Comment: Thank you @PoulBak.  How do I enable 'post'?  This is just running locally from VS at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **[405 Method Not Allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405)** indicates that the endpoint is not configured to accept a `POST` in this case. That is why your `OnPostAsync()` method is not being executed, the request was never routed to that endpoint.

For [Razor pages (Non MVC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/september/asp-net-core-simpler-asp-net-mvc-apps-with-razor-pages), the convention for `POST` is that you need to include an *action* or endpoint name, we use the `asp-page-handler="MyAction"` attribute to specify the method that will handle the request, by convention the method name should be in the format `OnPostMyActionAsync` for an *async* handler.

So let's change your form:

```
<form asp-page-handler="Upload" method="post">
    <!-- Put a file Upload control here ;) -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

You could also have placed this attribute on the submit button, this allows support for multiple handlers for the same form that will provide different actions:

```
<form method="post">
    <!-- Put a file Upload control here ;) -->
    <input asp-page-handler="Upload" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then in the code behind, change your handler to this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUploadAsync()
{
    return Page();
}
```

> It is common to use a verb that describes the overall intent for the method handler, things like `Add`, `Delete`, `Update`, then append `Item` or the record type if this is an action on a specific item on a page that shows many items.

Have a read over [File upload Scenarios in ASP.NET Core 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0#file-upload-scenarios) for other information related to both posting to form action handlers and how to use the `file` input form field.

- You could also try adding the `[HttpPost]` attribute to your endpoint, that might work around the issue in *Razor Pages* but it is simpler to understand and stick to the conventions, rather than subvert them.

---

Your code is however correct for an **MVC** application, *although you haven't hookedup the file upload control yet*, but so far its good. If I post that code you have directly into a blank MVC project (.Net 7) then it handles both the `GET` and `POST` requests as expected.

Comment: You only need to specify handlers when you want to handle multiple POSTs on one page. The convention simply _is_ OnPost(Async).

Comment: Probably one of the best, most detailed and thoughtful responses I've ever received on SO.  Thanks very much Chris.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand this question, nor the other answer nor the fact that it is accepted.

Your code works just fine:

[image: Razor Page accepting OnPost without handler]

You definitely don't *need* handlers to let your POST request end up in your `OnPost[Async]()` method.

The methods OnGet/OnPost(Async) are there by convention. Razor Pages is all about typing as little code as possible to get routing to a Razor page working.

Specifying handlers is to differentiate between multiple forms or buttons on the same page, invoking different actions.

Attributes for MVC also do nothing for Razor pages. If you apply an `[HttpPost]` attribute to your OnPost method, you get a warning from the MVC analyzer:

> Warning   MVC1002 'HttpPostAttribute' cannot be applied to Razor Page handler methods. Routes for Razor Pages must be declared using the @page directive or using conventions.

tl;dr: your code should just work. If your 405 error got resolved by specifying a handler, then the code in your question is a non-repro.

That being said: to make your form work for file uploads, you need to add the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.